# Creating a readtable with a disabled dispatch reader macro

Tags: macros, racket, reader-macro

I am creating a new language based on Racket and I don't want certain `#x` macros to work, such as the syntax-quote `#'`. How do I remove it so that `#'` does not do a syntax quote, but does whatever an unbound dispatch macro-char does?

I can do that with single-char macros by doing

```
(make-readtable (current-readtable)
                #\' #\a #f) ; set ' to be the same as a normal character
```

but I don't know how to do this for dispatch macros.

Comment: Not sure _exactly_ the result you want. Do you want `#'` to be treated as `'` -- e.g. `#'x` to become `'x` and `#'(x)` to become `'(x)`?  Or do you want the `#'` to be discarded completely? Or something else?

Comment: This has as much to do with Scheme as it does with CommonLisp.  Suggest removing the 'Scheme' tag.

Comment: @GregHendershott like I said, "How do I remove it so that `#'` does not do a syntax quote but does whatever an _unbound_ dispatch macro-char does?" i.e. I `#'` should do what `#@` and `##` do (assuming the user has not programmed them to do something), which is do an error.

Comment: What `##` does is give an error: `"read: bad syntax \`##'"`. Is that what you want `#'` to do?

Comment: @GregHendershott yes, exactly. I want to remove the functionality of it for my language, like I did in my example for the quote character.

Comment: I updated my answer. In that case I guess you simply have the `'dispatch-macro` call `raise-read-error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want `#'` to be treated as `'`:

Provide a `reader-proc` that simply calls the normal `read-syntax`:

```
#lang racket/base

(define (reader-proc ch in src line col pos)
  (read-syntax src in))

(define our-readtable (make-readtable (current-readtable)
                                      #\'
                                      'dispatch-macro
                                      reader-proc))

;; A `#:wrapper1` for `syntax/module-reader`, i.e. to use in your
;; lang/reader.rkt
(define (wrapper1 thk)
  (parameterize ([current-readtable our-readtable])
    (thk)))
(provide wrapper1)

;; tests
(module+ test
  (require rackunit
           racket/port)
  (parameterize ([current-readtable our-readtable])
    (check-equal? (with-input-from-string "#'foo" read)
                  'foo)
    (check-equal? (with-input-from-string "#'(foo)" read)
                  '(foo))
    (check-equal? (with-input-from-string "#'(foo #'(bar))" read)
                  '(foo (bar)))))
```

A slightly more complicated example of working with `'dispatch-macro` is the [lambda reader literal support I just recently added](https://github.com/greghendershott/rackjure/blob/master/rackjure/lambda-reader.rkt) to `#lang rackjure`.

---

**UPDATED**

Assuming you want `#'` to cause a read error, `"bad syntax: #'"`:

```
#lang racket/base

(require syntax/readerr)

(define (reader-proc ch in src line col pos)
  (raise-read-error (format "bad syntax: #~a" ch)
                    src line col pos 2))

(define our-readtable (make-readtable (current-readtable)
                                      #\'
                                      'dispatch-macro
                                      reader-proc))

;; A `#:wrapper1` for `syntax/module-reader`, i.e. to use in your
;; lang/reader.rkt
(define (wrapper1 thk)
  (parameterize ([current-readtable our-readtable])
    (thk)))
(provide wrapper1)

;; tests
(module+ test
  (require rackunit
           racket/port)
  (parameterize ([current-readtable our-readtable])
    (check-exn exn:fail? (λ () (with-input-from-string "#'foo" read)))))
```